# Values of the same pointer are different depending where I call it

Tags: c, pointers

My program is using a main function to prompt the user to choose which function to use and then sending the reference to a char double pointer to the function they choose. In the function, I allocate memory dynamically for the number of strings. Then, for each string, I allocate memory depending on the incoming string length.

```
void readFile(char *** fileAsArray){
   /* file name found, file opened, set to FILE *input */

   int numWords = 0;
   *fileAsArray = malloc(5000 * sizeof(**fileAsArray));
   while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), input){
      char *word = strtok(line, " \n");
      while(word){
         int wordSize = strlen(word);
         int i;
         (*fileAsArray)[numWords] = malloc(wordSize * sizeof((**fileAsArray)[numWords]));
         (*fileAsArray)[numWords] = word;
         printf("%s", (*fileAsArray)[numWords]); // CORRECT WHEN CALLED HERE
         numWords++;
         word = strtok(NULL, " \n");
      }
   }
      printf("%s", (*fileAsArray)[0]); //INCORRECT WHEN CALLED HERE??
}
```

Comment: `(*fileAsArray)[numWords] = word;` = instant memory leak of the `malloc` from just one line earlier. And if you think that's related to your problem, you're right.

Comment: You allocate memory, but you don't use allocated memory.

Comment: Also don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminate** byte string*. You need to allocate space for that null-terminator as well, and it's not counted by `strlen`.

Comment: Also instead of passing `char ***`, consider returning `char **`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         (*fileAsArray)[numWords] = malloc(wordSize * sizeof((**fileAsArray)[numWords]));
         (*fileAsArray)[numWords] = word;
```

Is overwriting the pointer to allocated buffer by `word` and causing memory leak.

`strcpy()` should be used to copy strings.

Also you forgot to allocate for teminating null-character.

The part should be:

```
         (*fileAsArray)[numWords] = malloc((wordSize + 1) * sizeof((**fileAsArray)[numWords]));
         strcpy((*fileAsArray)[numWords], word);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly to fix the issues I was having. I knew about the null-character, but it completely escaped my mind when doing this and I never considered it in the countless times I walked through my code. For the point about overwriting the pointer, does that mean when allocating memory using malloc that the memory has some value already? Or was my previous code basically ignoring the malloc by instantly setting that pointer to something different?Thanks again.

Comment: Memory allocated via `malloc()` has some value, but it is indeterminate and you shouldn't use that. And it is not the meaning of overwriting pointers.